# C++ templates is this possible?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I just started to learn about templates in C++ and do not know terminology well but this is what I want to do. Let's say I have three functions.

```
double fa(double a)
{
   return a;
}

double fb(double a, double b)
{
   return (a+b);
}

double fc(double a, double b, double c)
{
   return (a+b+c);
}
```

Let say I want to pass functions fa, fb or fc into a new function called compute:

```
void compute(double (*func)(double))
{
   func(1);
   std::cout << "1 argument here";
}

void compute(double (*func)(double, double))
{
   func(1,2);
   std::cout << "2 arguments here";
}

void compute(double (*func)(double, double, double))
{
   func(1,2,3);
   std::cout << "3 arguments here";
}
```

Is there any way to define a function "compute" without overloading functions but using templates instead? So I could pass a function with arbitrary number of arguments.

Comment: Are you always passing 1,2,3...?

Comment: This isn't Haskell or OCaml, C++ actually has multi-argument functions and not currying.  So it should be `void compute(double (*func)(double,double,double))`

Comment: Ops, fixed. Yes let's say always passing 1,2,3...

Answer (score 6):

Ben (another Ben) already suggested that what you want are variadic templates.

Here's a functor that does addition on a variable number of arguments:

```
struct {
    double operator()(double first) const
    {
        return first;
    }

    double operator()(double first, double second) const
    {
        return first + second;
    }

    template<typename... T>
    double operator()(double first, double second, T... t) const
    {
        return (*this)(first + second, t...);
    }
} variadic_add;
```

And you can call it like this:

```
template<typename Reducer>
void compute(Reducer reduce)
{
    reduce(1);
    std::cout << "1 arguments here";
    reduce(1,2);
    std::cout << "2 arguments here";
    reduce(1,2,3);
    std::cout << "3 arguments here";
    reduce(1,2,3,4);
    std::cout << "4 arguments here";
}

compute(variadic_add);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible: you'd use variadic templates to deduce both the type and the number of arguments, e.g.:

```
template <typename... T>
void compute(void (*func)(T...)) {
    func(/* magic goes here (see below) */);
    std::cout << sizeof...(T) << " arguments here\n";
}
```

The tricky business is the magic needed to pass on the right number of arguments. It is certainly doable, e.g., by generating a sequence of indices. The other detail left out from the code above is that `T` can vary arbitrarily. If you want to lock it down to be just for a sequence of `double`s, you can use suitable type traits together with `std::enable_if<cond, Type>` or `static_assert()`.